# Can you explain intuitively why the pole exists in this common-emitter circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, small-signal

This shows mathematically that common emitter circuit with the bypass capacitor \$C_e\$ has a pole.

Can you explain intuitively why the pole exists here?

[image]

Comment: What is intuitive to me might not seem intuitive to you. But -- you have a RC circuit (the three resistors to the left of the capacitor can be merged into one) and RC circuits have 1 pole.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy would there any more conditions for RC to be a pole? I think some RC doesn't create pole in the amplifier transfer function.

Comment: I can't think of a configuration where an RC circuit does not have a pole. But, to be honest, I'm a bit sleepy, so I may be missing something.

Comment: The zero is intuitive if you understand fast analytical circuit techniques or FACTs: when a zero occurs, the response is *nulled* (ac is 0 V, no current in \$R_c\$). What could imply a 0-V ac response in this circuit? A zero collector current --> then a zero base current. A zero base current occurs if the emitter is open or if the impedance made of \$C_e||R_e\$ is infinite. The root is the zero. For the pole, set the excitation to 0 V and determine the resistance \$R\$ "seen" from the cap. temporarily disconnected. It is a bit complicated in your case but that is the principle behind FACTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked at your circuit and and ran the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs over it. This is an intuitive method, which, in many cases, leads you to the answer without writing a line of algebra. I described this method in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject. In your case, you want to determine the current gain linking the collector current to the base current. I am however kind of puzzled by one of your intermediate sketch in which the \$i_c\$ source plugs to the ground rather than to the emitter. As a result, your end formula giving the transfer function is flagged as non-homogeneous by Mathcad.

Below is what I found, with an end formula written in a *low-entropy* form, with a unitless leading term (this is the dc current gain) and a pole and zero clearly expressed:

[image]

The principle is the following: first, set \$s=0\$ and open-circuit the capacitor \$C_E\$. Determine the dc gain linking the collector to the excitation current \$i_i\$. This is \$H_0\$ in my sheet. Then, set this excitation to 0 A (open-circuit the source) and determine the resistance \$R\$ "seen" from the capacitor connecting terminals while this latter is temporarily disconnected. This resistance times the capacitor gives the circuit time constant: \$\tau=RC_E\$. The pole is \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau}\$.

For the zero, you bring the stimulus back in the circuit and find an impedance combination which could lead to a nulled collector current. If you think backward, then a nulled collector current follows a nulled base current. The stimulus is back in place so the only way the base current disappears is when the emitter is ac-opened. This happens when the impedance made of \$C_E||R_E\$ becomes infinite at the zero frequency. The pole of this impedance is the zero we want: \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{R_EC_E}\$.

I have then captured the equivalent circuit in SIMetrix and ran the simulation. The magnitude and phase curves are superimposed with those coming from my equation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pole-zero pair, which is easy enough to see from a high level / hand-waving / intuitive method.

At low frequencies, Ce doesn't participate.  Gain must be lower (take lim \$s \rightarrow 0\$ to see this).

At high frequencies, Ce dominates, and Re does not.  Gain must be higher (this is the left factor, of R and h only; note the right factor reduces to \$\frac{s}{s} = 1\$) in lim \$s \rightarrow \infty\$).

We draw these two conditions as flat (horizontal) lines on the Bode diagram.  Somewhere inbetween, there must be a zero where gain ticks up, then a pole where it flattens back out.  The ratio between these frequencies equals the ratio of gains (because it's a first-order pair).  The farther apart they are in frequency, the higher the change in gain.  The closer they are, the less the change in gain, or if they're exactly on top of each other, they cancel out.  Evidently the lower corner frequency (the zero) is given by 1/(Re Ce), and the pole will be whatever above that -- a much more complicated expression since device parameters are involved.

Poles and zeros can't be placed arbitrarily in this circuit, but other networks can.  Consider the impedance divider made of resistors and capacitors in parallel.  The top pair (R1 || C1) has an impedance zero at the obvious frequency, as does the bottom pair (R2 || C2).  The input impedance (from the "top" of R1/C1) of course has zeroes, but the transfer function (from the input, to the midpoint between (R1 || C1) and (R2 || C2)) can have them cancel out, or be placed arbitrarily, one above the other.  Only when R1 C1 = R2 C2 do we have cancellation and flat frequency response (such a network is commonly used for high-frequency compensation of voltage probes).